# Taylor series in numerical differentiation

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm studying some numerical methods and especially the numerical differentiation.

I have some troubles with the central differentiation. How do you become from the Taylor series the formula for $f(x+h)$, $f(x-h)$, $f(x+2h)$ and $f(x-2h)$?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Take the ordinary formula and substitute $h$ for $-h,2h$ and $-2h$. (It even works with $0$ !)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from your first expression

$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n \tag{1}
$$

Call $y = x - a$, so that $x = a + y$. Eqn. (1) becomes

$$
f(y + a) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}y^n \tag{2}
$$

Now, to recover your second set of equations you can call $y \to h$ and $a\to x$, the result is

$$
f(x+h)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}h^n \tag{3}
$$

With $y\to 2h$, $\cdots$ you will recover the other equations

Comment: Thnx, but how do you become the equations f(x-h) and f(x-2h)?

Comment: @LeneCoenen In Eqn. (2) replace $y\to -h$ and $a\to x$

Comment: How do you know until which term you have to expand? And what does the O(h^4) for example mean?

Comment: @LeneCoenen The more terms you include the more accurate is your approximation.  The symbol $O(h^4)$ just means that the terms that follow are all going to be of order $h^4$ or higher.